# Database Sync on-premise to cloud

Tags: sql-server

I am getting involved in a new world.. database sync. I use SQL Server, and I have one local database and another one in the cloud. I am trying to sync those two databases just by pressing a button.

Does anybody has any experience doing these?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try SQL Server replication service. You can add remote servers as a linked servers. But you won't be able to do it by a click of a button though :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague and as such, my answer may seem vague too.

When generally speaking of syncing `Local <==> Cloud` I have personally been using a third party tool called RedGate SQL Toolbelt. The product is slightly on the pricey side, but the benefits offered are immense! You can easily compare and deploy structure and data changes at the click of a button.

<sub>(I have no affiliation to the product)</sub>